# Why it is not a indefinite loop as loop counter in while is outside the range of integer variable?

Tags: c++, c, loops, while-loop

```
{
int i=1;
while(i<=32767)
{
printf("%d",i);
i=i+1;
}
}
```

It seems a  simple program to print 1 to 32767 ...but when i reaches 32767 ...on incrementing value by 1.....it tries to go to 32768 which falls outside the range of integer and goes to other side that is -32768 .....due to which condition becomes true as i<=32767 i.e. -32768.....So it should work as indefinite loop.
My Dev C++ Compiler prints only 1 to 32767....its not working as indefinite loop.
Anybody

Comment: You might want to tell us about your plattform. For many current platforms `int` is bigger then 16bit (32bit is typical), so the program works just as it should (asside from the UB due to not initializing `i` at least)

Comment: **@downvoters** It will be better for the OP and for the site if downvoters also tell the reason for the downvote.There are people here who don't know how this site functions and what is needed to ask a proper question. So take a chill. Like OP here doesn't know how to address a comment `@Grizzly` !

Comment: @SahilGarg why do you put so much dots in your question ? and when you ask a question specify as much details as you can.

Comment: @Grizzly My platform:- I am using 64-bit Windows 7 and Dev C++ Compiler(32-bit) ..

Answer (score 10):

Presumably the size of an integer on your platform is > 16 bits.

ISO/IEC 9899:201x states

> minimum value for an object of type int
>
> INT_MIN -32767 // −(2<sup>15</sup> − 1)

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

In fact, most C compilers these days, on most platforms, will have larger integers than 16 bits.

In C, an integer is guaranteed to be *at least* 16 bits.  It is dangerous and non-portable to make an assumption that it is a specific size.  Always check.

Comment: It's usually at least 32 bits nowadays, and possibly 64. Print out INT_MAX (in limits.h) to see how big it can be.

Comment: +1, try `int16_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @Robert: Which platforms have `64bit` `int`? Most 64bit platforms I know have `int` as 32bit

Comment: Patience! It's long to explain. "In C, an integer is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits" - that's just wrong. The only thing that the Standard guarantees is that `sizeof(char) = 1` and `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` - and even `char` need not be exactly 8 bit, so `int` can even be 7 bits long...

Comment: @H2CO2 the Standard also guarantuees maximum `INT_MIN` and minimum `INT_MAX` value. So `int` is at least 16-bit wide.

Comment: @H2CO3: The standard guarantees certain ranges for the integer types, which for `int` guarantee that it can't be expressed with less then 16bit

Comment: @H2CO3: From §5.2.4.2.1, `INT_MAX` should be at least 32767.

Comment: @H2CO3: Hmm... then Wikipedia is wrong.  I'll have a look at the standard (unless you have a handy link...) and update either my answer or Wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: @H2CO3, anyway, I think downvoting for this reason is a bit harsh, I'd rather consider adding a smart* comment instead.

Comment: Oh, right. Though this is C99-only, it seems.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Some of my questions/answers were downvoted for reasons like this, and literally nobody cared - I see I wasn't right here, I revoked my downvote, no need to be bitter about that.

Comment: @H2CO3: No. The minimum limits on integer type ranges were present in C standard since C89/90.

Comment: @AndreyT is then Wikipedia really wrong? I see the 'C99' label next to all these...

Comment: Updated my answer to reference ISO/IEC 9899:201x

Comment: @H2CO3, feeling vindictive? ;-) It wasn't necessarily Eric. And no, I'm not bitter and I'm happy to see you revoked your dv. Just expressed my opinion, I don't even expect you to agree with what I *think*.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm not sure which specific label you are referring to, but it might apply to something more local. Firstly, `LLONG_MIN` was introduced in C99 only, so the label might apply to `LLONG_MIN` alone. Secondly, the limits were updated in C99 so the actual values might be C99-specific. But the limits themselves existed in C89/90 already.

Comment: @EricJ.  *In fact, most C compilers these days, on most platforms, will have larger integers than 16 bits.* still this is a common underestimation of the  8-bit microcontroller market. 8-bit microcontrollers are everywhere around you.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, are you sure the range of `int` on your platform overflows at `32767`? Most modern platforms use 4-byte `int`, meaning that its range is much much larger than `-32768..+32767`.

Secondly, signed integer overflow produces undefined behavior in C and C++. Your expectation of `32767` turning into `-32768` on increment and the loop becoming infinite is completely unfounded. The language does not guarantee anything like that. Your program may simply crash at the moment when overflow occur (some compilers can purposely generate code that ensures that the program gets interrupted on such overflow).

Thirdly, some modern compilers implement so called *strict overflow semantics* (GCC being one example). Since signed integer overflow produces undefined behavior, the compiler is free to translate the code in any way it sees fit. The compiler can translate it into an unconditional infinite loop. Or it can translate it into some more-or-less well-defined terminating loop.

Comment: *At least* 4 byte ints.  8 bytes is becoming quite common.